# jQuery convert DOM element to different type

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to convert a DOM element to a different type (as in HTML tag name, `a` to `p` in this case), but still retain all the original elements attributes. Whether they are valid for the new type or not doesn't matter in this case.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

I've looked at just creating a new element and copying the attributes across, but this isn't without it's own complications. In Firefox, `DOMElement.attributes` helpfully only includes attributes with a value, but in IE it reports all possible attributes for that element. The `attributes` property itself is read-only, so no way to copy that.

Comment: create a new duplicate, with exception of changing the type, then removing the old one?

Comment: @thephpdeveloper I don't understand, that's just cloning the element and replacing it, not changing the HTML element type.

Comment: by "element type", do you mean the tag name (e.g. "div")?

Comment: @J-P yes (why is yes not legitimate comment?!?)

Comment: It's one of the worst techniques probably but how about `parent.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML.replace("<old", "<new")` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sans-jQuery solution:

```
function makeNewElementFromElement( tag, elem ) {

    var newElem = document.createElement(tag),
        i, prop,
        attr = elem.attributes,
        attrLen = attr.length;

    // Copy children 
    elem = elem.cloneNode(true);
    while (elem.firstChild) {
        newElem.appendChild(elem.firstChild);
    }

    // Copy DOM properties
    for (i in elem) {
        try {
            prop = elem[i];
            if (prop && i !== 'outerHTML' && (typeof prop === 'string' || typeof prop === 'number')) {
                newElem[i] = elem[i];
            }
        } catch(e) { /* some props throw getter errors */ }
    }

    // Copy attributes
    for (i = 0; i < attrLen; i++) {
        newElem.setAttribute(attr[i].nodeName, attr[i].nodeValue);
    }

    // Copy inline CSS
    newElem.style.cssText = elem.style.cssText;

    return newElem;
}
```

E.g.

```
makeNewElementFromElement('a', someDivElement); // Create anchor from div
```

Comment: This is nice. What does this do wrt events attached to child elements? Do they get copied over too? (I'm thinking of IE and `attachEvent`). Would the first `while` loop be better served by `newElem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML`?

Comment: This doesn't copy over events bound by `attachEvent` or `addEventListener`. AFAIK, there's no way to access event handlers registered via either of those methods. Also, `innerHTML` doesn't capture DOM properties, only attributes and content.

Comment: Can't be upvoted enough. Good answer. No JQuery. Copies attributes. Copies DOM properties. Well done, lovely!

Answer (score 3):

while not a complete solution, the logic would basically be:

Save your existing element:

```
var oldElement = $(your selector here);
```

create a new element and insert it just before or after your oldElement

copy the attributes

```
  oldElement.attr().each(function(){
    copy old
    });
```

better yet, here is an example of a plug-in that does just what you want:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/getAttributes

Comment: Brilliant, that'll do! Didn't realise attr() would return all attributes, and it fixes IE by only returning attributes with a value.

Comment: @J-P  for some reason it worked the first time I tried it, but you're right it can't be called by that (I blame Firebug...)

Comment: there is a plugin to copy all attributes, if I find the reference I will add that.

Answer (score 0):

A more modern (2020+) approach is:

```js
function changeTag (element, tag) {
    // prepare the elements
    const newElem = document.createElement(tag)
    const clone = element.cloneNode(true)

    // move the children from the clone to the new element
    while (clone.firstChild) {
      newElem.appendChild(clone.firstChild)
    }

    // copy the attributes
    for (const attr of clone.attributes) {
      newElem.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value)
    }
    return newElem
  }
```

Compared to @James answer, you don't need to copy the `cssText` because it's already taken care by the browser. You also don't need the string/number dom properties since those are also properly migrated. It's also best to work on the cloned node only, not both of them (clone and elem)

Answer (score 0):

The following `replaceTag(element, tagName)` function replaces the provided `element` with a new element of type `tagName`, e.g. `replaceTag(someElement, 'p')`.

```js
// BEGIN actual function
function replaceTag(element, tagName) {
  const newElement = document.createElement(tagName);
  newElement.append(...element.childNodes);
  
  for (const attribute of element.attributes) {
    newElement.setAttribute(attribute.name, attribute.value);
  }
  
  element.replaceWith(newElement);
  return newElement;
}
// END actual function


// BEGIN from here onwards, example usage code
function divSpan2PEm() {
  const divElements = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  for (divElement of divElements) {
    const containedSpanElements = divElement.querySelectorAll(':scope > span');
    for (containedSpanElement of containedSpanElements) {
      replaceTag(containedSpanElement, 'em'); 
    }
    
    replaceTag(divElement, 'p');
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
}

[role="complementary"] {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

span {
  background-color: orange;
}

[data-bing] {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div role="complementary">
  <span>foo <strong>so strong</strong></span>
  <span data-bing="true">bar</span>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="divSpan2PEm()">Convert div-span to p-em</button>
```

`replaceTag` *moves* any existing children to the new element, as well as recreates any attributes. It does not and cannot replace any references to the original element, e.g. attached event handlers. Also, in general the interim and resulting HTML / updated DOM may not be valid.