# Using jQuery to change all instances of <object> to <iframe> for IE support

Tags: jquery, iframe, object, internet-explorer

I am wondering if it is possible to use jQuery to switch out all `<object>` tags on a site for `<iframe>` tags when loading on IE 8 and below. In essence, this would allow the page to be `XHTML 1.1` valid and not have to be double-coded all the time, eliminating the need to spend so much time focusing on non-standard browsers.

The `data=` attribute would need to be changed to `src=`, I'd like to insert `frameborder="0"`, and all of the `style` values for the `<object>` tag would also need to be set for the `<iframe>` tag.

My goal here is *not* to create a debate on `<iframe>`s vs `<object>`s, I just think that this would be a huge tmie saver, and encourage proper, strict `xhtml` coding practices.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Can you really call the output strict xhtml if it doesn't conform until modified client-side?

Comment: @David he wants to do it the other way round: He wants to output strict HTML and then do the IE6 fixes after loading.

Answer (score 1):

For a basic rundown on how to change an element's type see [jQuery convert DOM element to different type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206892/jquery-convert-dom-element-to-different-type) (no idea whether it'll work properly in XHTML, but it well might), but I don't think this is a good idea at all. I can see it cause delays on older machines (on which IE6 runs), and obviously, it won't work when JavaScript is disabled. All that to achieve valid code? Not a good idea IMO.

Before doing that, if the code has to be valid under any circumstances, I'd consider serving different code to IE6 on server side.

Comment: For what I am doing a lack of JavaScript support isn't an issue.

Plus I've found that the odds of having a device without JavaScript is very rare now. All new phones in the last few years support JavaScript and most people don't keep a phone for more than 2 years.

I'll check out the link you sent me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you can *change* the DOM element type, but you can always create a new IFRAME element and delete the old element instead.

Something like (caution: untested!)

```
$("object").each(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    $("<iframe/>").attr({
        src: obj.attr("data"),
        style: obj.attr("style"),
        frameborder: 0
    })
    .after(obj);

    obj.remove();
});
```

Comment: I'm having trouble testing your code. It is not placing the created iframe after the object. So after the object is removed there is nothing left.