# Replace an element name while retaining the attributes with jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes, tags, element, bold

I'm trying to create a jquery setup where all instances of `<i>` are changed to `<em>`. It's easy enough to do with:

```
$("i").each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($('<em>' + this.innerHTML + '</em>'));
});
```

But what I am having trouble figuring out is how to change all the `<i>` tags but retain each ones individual attributes. So if I have `<i style="background-color: #333;" alt="Example" title="Example">Example Text</i>` I would like it to change to `<em style="background-color: #333;" alt="Example" title="Example">Example Text</em>`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Wrong approach IMO.

I'd recommend replacing the actual elements themselves directly in the DOM. Maybe this question helps:

[jQuery convert DOM element to different type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206892/jquery-convert-dom-element-to-different-type)

Answer (score 0):

It is simple

$(this).attributes(); will get you all the attributes of the i tag for every instance simply place it into your replace function.

I am not sure how can you play with a function but in my knowledge code will be something like this.

> ```
> $("i").each(function(){
> var attribute = $(this).attributes();
> $(this).replaceWith($('<em'+attributes+'>'
> ```
>
> + this.innerHTML + ''));
>       });

Hope it helps.