# How to clone an element and change its DOM type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to clone a DOM element, with all of its children (including data and listeners), but I want the resulting clone to have a different DOM type.

E.g. I want to convert:

```
<td>
 <p class="pclass">
  Hello
 </p>
 <p class="pclass">
  World!
 </p>
</td>
```

To a new element containing:

```
<div>
 <p class="pclass">
  Hello
 </p>
 <p class="pclass">
  World!
 </p>
</div>
```

NB: I already have an answer but as it may interrest other people and as the answer is not perfect but sufficient, I created this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following jQuery script will do the job:

```
var oldElement = $(your selector here);
var newElement = $('<my new HTML tag>').append($(oldElement).contents().clone(true, true));
```

This script PRESERVES the element **children** data and event listeners (cf. clone(true, true)).
This script DOESN'T PRESERVE the element **itself** data and event listeners.

NB: It could be interresting that someone propose a complement to preserve the original element data and event listeners. A start of answer is proposed there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2207117/2227298